# Please evaluate the following statement (related to post increment and pre increment)

Tags: java

When I execute the code it gives me 13 as an answer. Please explain how the computer derives the answer.  I want to know the priority of pre- and post- increment.

```
class demo
{
public static void main(String [] arg)
     {
      int i=2;
      System.out.println(i++ + i + ++i + i++);
     }
}
```

Comment: Q:  I want to know the priority of pre and post incrementing.  A: Pre- and post-increment have the same "precedence".  You want to know the precedence of "increment" vs "addition".  Google "Java operator precedence":  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html.  FYI, this expression is "undefined behavior" in C and C++.

Comment: Ya got it.. And I would see to it that I ask the question in a more constructive way next time. Newbie here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think operator precedence is really an issue here; there seems to be a clear order of operations.  Moving from left to right:

```
(i++) + i + (++i) + (i++)

  2   + 3 +   4   +   4   = 13
```

`++i` implies that i gets incremented prior to reading its value 
`i++` indicates that i should be read first and then incremented.

**Note**: the increment operator has a higher precendence than the addition operator. (Per the comments) here is a good [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: Ya I agree with you but after you perform the fourth operation(i++), don't we increment the total answer by 1 because its a post-increment(i++)?

Comment: No, dude.  Because "operator precedence" binds "++" before "+".  The expression is exactly as Joel parenthesized it.  Look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: That last post-increment won't affect the current calculation.  Its only purpose would be to affect the result of other calculations that occur after this one.

Answer (score 0):

`i++` means that i is incremented, after it is "used", whereas `++i` means i is incremented before it is "used"
Thus your expression is:
  2 (take i as it is and increment it afterwards)
+ 3 (take the incremented i and don't change it at all)
+ 4 (increment i before taking it)
+ 4 (take i as it is and increment it afterwards)
= 13 (i is now 5)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int i = 2;
    // System.out.println(i++ + i + ++i + i++);
    int temp;

    temp = i++;
    System.out.println(temp); // 2 since [temp = 2] [i = 3]
    temp = i;
    System.out.println(temp); // 3 since [temp = 3] [i = 3]
    temp = ++i;
    System.out.println(temp); // 4 since [temp = 4] [i = 4]
    temp = i++;
    System.out.println(temp); // 4 since [temp = 4] [i = 5]
}
```